# Ruby on Rails - Cocoon gem, Don't Pre-populate existing/added posts in edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

My application has models `Campaign` & `Post`, I have:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, inverse_of: :campaign
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
```

*My form:*

```
= simple_form_for(@campaign) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :title
  #posts
    = f.simple_fields_for :posts do |post|
      = render 'post_fields', f: post
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'Add Post', f, :posts, wrap_object: Proc.new {|post| post.user_id = current_user.id; post }
```

I use `Cocoon gem` for `nested_forms`.

When I go to my `campaigns#edit` view, I can see all `posts` that were already added to a `campaign` *(natural behavior of the gem)*, and I can add new posts to my campaign and/or edit existing `posts` .

I have also a button that has this *param:* `add_to: 'existing_campaign'` and what I am trying to achieve is, if my link has `?add_to=existing_campaign`, I don't want to **show/Pre-populate** any of the `posts` that were already added to `campaign`, so user can only add new `posts` to the `campaign`

My `link_to` looks like: 
`= link_to 'Add Post', edit_campaign_path(campaign, add_to: 'existing_campaign'),`

*short explain: if edit link has param `?add_to=existing_campaign`, I don't Pre-populate already added `posts`, if param doesn't exists, I Pre-populate `posts`*

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an `attr_accessor` in campaign to control whether or not existing posts should be seen...

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor hide_posts
  ...
end
```

Set the value in your `edit` method

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @campaign.hide_posts = params[:add_to] == 'existing_campaign'
    ...
  end
```

Ensure the temporary variable is in your strong parameters (so that redisplay after failed update remembers to hide posts)

```
def campaign_params
  params.require(:campaign).permit( :hide_posts, ...
```

Now on your view you can do...

```
= f.hidden_field :hide_posts
= f.simple_fields_for :posts do |post|
  = render('post_fields', f: post) unless @campaign.hide_posts && post.object.persisted?
```

Comment: I like attaching it to the @campaign object!  If the param is in his url, where on the form would the hide_posts display on a redisplay after failing to update?

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Steve

Comment: @mirv on update the url params are not considered, but excellent point, I forgot to include the `hide_posts` in the form.  Edit done! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Updating with more specifics ...**

You as the design need to decide if you want to move the logic to a helper.  If you aren't aware of skinny controller / fat model or another strategy for organizing your codebase read this ... [Link](http://codefol.io/posts/Where-Do-I-Put-My-Code). For now, I'm going to assume you will use a helper.

**The theory & some nitpicky things** ...

What's going to happen with skinny controller is you need that parameter accessible in the view logic (but that would be insecure and violate the rails way).  Since you shouldn't just expose params to the view, you instead are passing the message containing the parameter's value. Object orientation teaches us to use pass messages.  Rails says to use instances variables (@something) in the controller and the view has access to those.

We need to setup the conditional logic next.  One of the Rails ways is to use helpers to remove extraneous logic from the view or make it readable.  This qualifies as something that unless you have another reason I'm not aware of - this should be in a helper.  I would be tempted here to just test for boolean and call another partial for the extra view you make.

Which means I have to assume your tests will change too (if not done in a standard way, you have to include  to get access to that method/object).

---

**Specific to your question**

1. `link_to`on the page calling the nested form should be true/false...

> `= link_to 'Add Post', edit_campaign_path(campaign, show_posts: false)`

3. Your controller will have `@show_posts` in whatever action of the campaign controller you are using (edit or new usually). You need to set `@show_posts = params[:show_posts]`
4. Write the helper ...

> ```
> helpers/campaign_helper.rb
>
> def showPosts?(show_posts)
>   testPart == true ? 'only_comment' : 'post_fields'  
> end
> ```

4. A new partial ... which is basically the same, but drops the `simple_fields_for` loop which populates the other posts.
5. Your _form partial will change from what you had above to ...

> ```
> = f.simple_fields_for :posts do |post|
>   = render 'posts_fields', f: post
> ```

To ...

> ```
> ...
> #posts
>   = render showPosts?(@show_posts), f: post
> ...
> ```

Update, I tested all the parts & got it working with your exact syntax - I ended up using ternary operator in the helper.

Comment: Thanks @Mirv. `cocoon` only has one partial to call, which in my case is `_post_fields.html.erb`. Which other partial can I can?

Comment: I'll get some coffee and poke this in the next hour or two...only got 4 hrs sleep.  Are you ok with helpers in your tests?

Comment: Aye, but the answers help me decide how much work I need to do in order to get you rolling.  What's your experience?  Do you know about including objects into your rails tests?

Comment: I know enough :) I don't use tests ENV that much, since I test everything on development first. And I dont thing we need to run anything on Test ENV since its just including partials.

Comment: I'm not certain if you are saying you want to block editing of existing posts or to not show those posts or show them, but pop up an empty field so the use doesn't have to click the add button ... I can pretty much answer without knowing this but was just pondering

Comment: What Im saying is, not to show those posts when the `param` is `present`.

Comment: This extra parameter thing kind of smells like you should just be directing to the post#new action ... but I'm not really advanced enough to say if that's certain (also if using java to serve the pages up it can just make a mini of that logic to pass) - the answer using cocoon is almost done though, give me like 10 more minutes.

Comment: Im only using that param on `campaigns#edit`. `campaign#new` will have the same setup as in `cocoon` and no params or changes. Thanks man :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143503/discussion-between-mirv-and-user6589814).